# Continuity on closed and bounded implies uniform continuity?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I have come across this theorem:

> Theorem: A continuous function $f$ into $\mathbb R$ on a closed bounded interval $[a,b]$ in uniformly continuous on $[a,b]$.

My doubt is this: obviously $\frac{1}{x}$ isn't uniformly continuous on $[a,b]$. Is it because $\frac 1x$ isn't defined on $\mathbb R$? ( as $\infty$ does not belong in $\mathbb R$) or is it some other reason that I am missing.

Comment: $\frac{1}{x}$ is uniformly continuous on any closed bounded interval in which it is defined.

Comment: As long as $0 \notin [a,b]$, then $f$ is continuous.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews ,  So you guys are saying that the theorem holds true as long as the function is defined in the interval , hence since the function isn't defined at 0 , it doesn't hold true for the interval that I am considering

Comment: That's what the theorem says: "a continuous function on ... $[a,b]$" means a function that is defined and continuous on that closed interval. It doesn't allow for functions that are not defined on that interval.